# Is there any way to stop rpy2 from converting everything automatically?

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2, factor-analysis

I'm using rpy2 in order to be able to use the package [FMradio](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/FMradio/versions/1.1.1) in Python. This package consists of a specific pipeline for exploratory factor analysis so I'm using the output of a function as input of the next one. However, this package heavily depends on column names on matrices to do the calculations. The automatic conversions from numpy2ri and pandas2ri erases the column and row names of matrices thus making it impossible to use this package.

I thought that the simplest way to bypass this problem would be to not convert the R matrices into python arrays and just use R objects until I don't need it anymore. Is there any way to stop the automatic conversion from happening and just dealing with R objects on python?

This is how I'm trying to use it. *X_filt* is an empty vector because the conversion from R matrix to numpy.array erases the column names from *correlation*. *X* must be a matrix for the function subSet to work, so converting it to a pandas dataframe is not an option.

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
FMradio = importr("FMradio")
stats = importr("stats")


correlation = stats.cor(X, method = "pearson", use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
correlation_filt = FMradio.RF(correlation, t = 0.9)
X_filt = FMradio.subSet(X, correlation_filt)
regular_correlation = FMradio.regcor(X_filt, 10, verbose = FALSE)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Calling `activate()` is actually asking rpy2 to convert everything.

The documentation about conversion outlines how conversion is working:
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/robjects_convert.html#conversion

If conversion from and to `pandas` is the only thing you need, the relevant section in the doc is probably enough:
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/pandas.html